# How do you find current internet network interface?

Tags: networking, route, ifconfig

How do I find the network interface that's connected to the Internet?

This machine could typically be connected via `{eth0,eth1,usb0,wlan0}`. The best I could think of is:

```
sudo route | grep default | awk '{print $NF}'
```

**Update**: My favoured solution is:

```
 $(for i in `ip r`; do echo $i; done | grep -A 1 dev | tail -n1)
```

Comment: The Internet should be accessed normally via default gateway. You can use the command `sudo route | grep UG | awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: @Khaled, there can be more than one interfaces using gateways(Flag G).  So your answer is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get the default gateway in LINUX given the destination?](http://serverfault.com/questions/47915/how-do-i-get-the-default-gateway-in-linux-given-the-destination)

Comment: 12:02 <biz> hendry: route -n | awk '/^0\.0\.0\.0/{print $NF}'  or  ip route list 0.0.0.0/0 | sed -n 's/default.*dev \([^[:space:]]\+\)/\1/p'  or parsing /proc/net/route 
            on Linux... it seems there's no portable way to do that

Comment: Thinking of tweaking my question to find the IP of the connected interface too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it will be better to use iproute2 instead old and bad-working route.

```
ip r | sed -n '/^de/s/.*dev //p'
```

Comment: +1. I agree. Though I have provided answer using `route` command, We should use iproute2 commands wherever possible.

Comment: `x220:~$ ip r | sed -n '/^de/s/.*dev //p'
eth0  metric 202` I think the regexp can be improved. Gah, why is it soo difficult to parse?

Comment: Your solution isn't perfect, I have a "metric 202" suffix. I've added my solution in the question above and accepted your answer, since I've grateful you have showed me `ip r`. :)

Comment: nice idea, but awk seems the better tool for that task:

`ip r | awk '/^de/{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 1):

`route -n | awk '$1 ~ /0.0.0.0/ {print $NF}'` will give you interface with default gateway which is most probably the interface through which you are accessing internet.